# Consuming entries of a ConfigMap created from property files

Tags: docker, kubernetes

The example on the documentation (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/) for consuming values is based on a ConfigMap where each data entry is a single pair/value. Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  special.how: very
  special.type: charm
```

However when we create a ConfigMap from property files, every data entry value is itself a list of key/pair values. Example:

```
$ kubectl get configmaps game-config -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: game-config
  [...]
data:
  game.properties: |-
    enemies=aliens
    lives=3
    enemies.cheat=true
    enemies.cheat.level=noGoodRotten
    secret.code.passphrase=UUDDLRLRBABAS
    secret.code.allowed=true
    secret.code.lives=30
  [...]
```

In such a case:

1. How do we consume a single entry (example: enemies.cheat) as an
   environment variable?
2. How do we consume all the entries (example: all game.properties entries)
   as a set of environment variables, assuming we just use each key as
   the environment variable name?

Answer (score 4):

You can't consume a single entry since it is just one big blob of text. You have two options that I see:

1. Don't create the config map from a file. Instead create each entry in the ConfigMap manually. You'll have to consume each key separately though, at least until [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26299) is resolved.
2. Don't use the ConfigMap as environment variables. Instead mount that key as a volume and have your application read the key/values.

It seems like the second option would work nicely for you. It would let you continue to generate your ConfigMap from a file, and also allow you to consume all declared key/values without having to constantly change your Kubernetes manifests.

Another advantage of mounting your ConfigMap as a volume is that it will allow you to perform in-place updates to your configs (assuming that your app tolerates that). If you mount ConfigMap keys as environment variables the only way to update them is to restart the app.